# How to protect encryptor parameters themselfs

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I found some code that is fine for my objectives to encrypt/decrypt string.

But I have to distribute the appplication to client and there is no way to keep

```
    static readonly string PasswordHash = "P@@Sw0rd";
    static readonly string SaltKey = "S@LT&KEY";
    static readonly string VIKey = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";
```

outside of the application.

App must decrypt data and I have to keep those parameters inside of app/windows somehow.

I am wondering if there is a way to protect this things or at least hide somehow...

Thanks!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6a2836a-d587-4068-8630-94f4fb2a2aeb/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-c

```
static readonly string PasswordHash = "P@@Sw0rd";
static readonly string SaltKey = "S@LT&KEY";
static readonly string VIKey = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8";

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);

            byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
            var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros };
            var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));

            byte[] cipherTextBytes;

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    cryptoStream.Close();
                }
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
        {
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            byte[] keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PasswordHash, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SaltKey)).GetBytes(256 / 8);
            var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged() { Mode = CipherMode.CBC, Padding = PaddingMode.None };

            var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(VIKey));
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
            var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];

            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount).TrimEnd("\0".ToCharArray());
        }
```

Comment: Anything your application can do, the client can also do.  You need to read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx.

Comment: @SLaks Well.. True.. But I am thinking to implement some functions that will be able construct those parameters somehow... I just do not want hardcode it directly...

Comment: That will do very little code.  Your attacker can simply call that function.

Comment: Congratulations, you discovered the problem of DRM. DRM does not work. You can obfuscate it and make it more annoying to get the key out, but that's about it. If the attacker wants to get it, he is getting it.

Comment: @JanSchejbal Unless the platform is controlled by you, yes, and if it is in the hands of the whole world that is *almost* impossible to achieve.